# How to pass parameters to VF component for getContentasPDF

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm trying to use getContentasPDF on a custom VF page which references a VF component. This VF page is not exposed on UI to users and it's sole purpose is for generating it as PDF and saving/sending it as an attachment.

I am passing the record ID `rId` in the method so that only child records are retrieved for the `rId` in the PDF(This is done using the controller on the VF component). But some default records are getting retrieved in PDF. Even preview of VF page returns some default records.

How to return only associated records passed in the method?

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page Controller="ReportPDF" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold" value="Blah Blah --.">
  <apex:param name="q" value="{!expreportid}"/>
  </apex:outputText>
  <c:ExpenseComponent expense_report="{!expreportid}"> 
  </c:ExpenseComponent>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex class**

```
    public class ReportPDF {

        public String expreportid { get; set; }

               @future(callout=true)
                public static void sendPDF(Id rId, Id recipientId){
                    blob body;
                    pageReference pageref = page.ExpensePDF;
                    pageRef.getParameters().put('q',rId);

                    try{
                         body = pageref.getContentAsPDF();
                       }

                    catch(calloutException ce)
                      {
                      ExceptionLogging.addException('ExpenseReportPDF',ce);
                      }

                      Attachment pdfatt = new Attachment();

                      pdfatt.parentid = reportId;
                      pdfatt.body = body;
                      pdfatt.name = 'test';

                  try{
                      insert pdfatt;
                     }
                  catch(DMLexception de){
                      ExceptionLogging.addException('ExpenseReportPDF',de);
                      }


}
```

**VF Component Controller**

```
 public class FindExpenseLines {

 public id reportid {get;set;}

 public List<Expense_Item__c> getExpenseItems() {
 return [select Source__c, Destination__c, Mode__c,
    Kms_Travelled__c, Expense_Incurred__c, createdby.name, createdby.EmployeeNumber from expense_item__c where Expense_Report__c =:reportid];
    }
}
```

**VF Component**

```
<apex:component controller="FindExpenseLines" access="Global">
 <apex:attribute name="expense_report" type="Id" assignTo="{!reportId}" description="Id of the expense report"/>

 <table border = "2" cellspacing = "5">
        <tr>
            <td>Appointment Time</td>
            <td>Exp Item Number</td>
            <td>Exp Report</td>
            <td>Client Visited</td>
            <td>Agency Visited</td>
            <td>Lead Visited</td>
            <td>Source Location</td>
            <td>Destination Location</td>
            <td>Mode of Travel</td>
            <td>Amount of Expenditure</td>               
        </tr>

        <apex:repeat value="{!expenseItems}" var="item">
        <tr>
            <td>{!item.Appoint_Start_Time__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Name}</td>
            <td>{!item.Expense_Report__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Client_Name__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Agency_Name__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Lead_Name__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Source__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Destination__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Mode_of_Travel__c}</td>
            <td>{!item.Expense_Incurred__c}</td>              
        </tr>
        </apex:repeat>        
 </table>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: So, you have a controller for `<c:ExpenseComponent/>` that is supposed to query records based on `expense_report`? Any chance we can see that too? Also, what is calling `sendPDF`?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I've added the component controller. `sendPDF`  - I am gonna  call this on a TriggerHandler (Tony's tidy pattern)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are passing `rId` as `q` in on the URL in your Apex, wouldn't you then want to use it in your visualforce like this?

```
<apex:page Controller="ReportPDF" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:outputText style="font-style:bold" value="Blah Blah --.">
  </apex:outputText>
  <c:ExpenseComponent expense_report="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.q}"> 
  </c:ExpenseComponent>
</apex:page>
```

To test the output, you can see what appears if you manually build your URL in the browser as:

```
https://<pod>.salesforce.com/apex/ReportPDF?q=<some id>
```

If you still get rogue records, I would suggest something is amiss in the controller for `<c:ExpenseComponent/>`.

Comment: Did you omit `<apex:param name="q" value="{!expreportid}"/>` advertently ?

Comment: Yes, i wasn't sure what it was for....what is it for?

Comment: Sorry, VFnoob here! I learnt that `<apex:param` is used to getting & setting parameters for a VF page. So was trying to pass `ID` from the controller

Comment: I don't think you need it, you're going to pass in the parameter from the URL to your component, you can reference it as shown in the answer

Comment: VF won't compile as type of the attribute in component is `ID`. `Wrong type for attribute <c:expensecomponent expense_report="{$CurrentPage.parameters.q}">. Expected Id, found String`

Comment: Make sure there isn't a space at the end of `{!$CurrentPage.parameters.q}`, my example had one in i'm afraid

Comment: The pdf still returns rogue records. The URL looks fine. What possibly could be wrong in the component controller?

Comment: Where and how is `reportid` getting set in your controller?

Comment: Hi Phil, I was using the VF email template, VF component & controller in an approval process, the VF email template is working fine just like URL is working fine in this case. Thought of leveraging the same here.

Comment: I can only advise that `reportid` isn't set properly, it's difficult to see without seeing your entire class and component.

Comment: So, I just mocked this up in my DE org and it works perfectly. I took your page, component and controller and used Contact (instead of expense) and it worked fine as far as inserting the attachment (i didn't test the email). You're either not describing the circumstances very well, or something else is at play. I'm out now I'm afraid :(

Comment: Thanks for your help Phil! I was doing daft in my class, I was using `reportId` instead of the parameter `q`

Comment: cool glad you sorted it

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller constructor using `ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameter.get('q');`  get the ID and assign to `expreportid` . It will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm passing ID in the static method's parameter. How will constructor be called in that case?

Comment: @Bennie ` pageReference pageref = page.ExpensePDF;
                    pageRef.getParameters().put('q',rId);
` I am talkiing about this. Get this value in page constructor and hen use. Or get in page using as @Phil suggested.

Comment: I've followed what Phil suggested, the URL `https://<pod>.salesforce.com/apex/ReportPDF?q=<some id>` works fine but the pdf is still returns some rogue records.

Comment: check if you are getting correct Id in component .